Hirsch's proof of Morse–Sard Theorem
I am studying Morse–Sard Theorem from Hirsch's book Differential Topology and I fail to understand the proof of one of the preparatory lemmas.

Proposition. Let $M$ and $N$ be manifolds with $\dim M < \dim N$. If $f: M \to N$ is a $\mathcal{C}^1$ map, then $f(M)$ is nowhere dense.

Hirsch states that it's sufficient to prove that $f(M)$ has measure zero, which is fairly obvious. Then he claims that this follows from the fact that if $U \subset \mathbb{R}^m$ is an open set, then $g(U)$ also has zero measure for $\mathcal{C}^1$ map $g: U \to \mathbb{R}^n$ with $m < n$, but I cannot see this. Why is it true?

@TedShifrin That's my fault, I edited the post.

What are you asking? Why can we reduce to the problem about $g$, or why the problem with $g$ is true?

@Aphelli The first one

We assume (for obvious reasons) that $M$ has constant dimension $m$ and $N$ has constant dimension $n$.
Lemma: there exists countable families $(U_i)_i$ of open subspaces of $M$ and $(V_i)_i$ of subspaces of $N$ such that every $U_i$ (resp. $V_i$) is diffeomorphic to an open subset $U’_i$ of $\mathbb{R}^m$ (resp. $V’_i$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$) and $f(U_i) \subset V_i$.
Proof of the claim assuming the Lemma: for each $i$, $f: U_i \rightarrow V_i$ induces (after pre- and post-composing by a diffeomorphism) a $\mathcal{C}^1$ map $f_i: U’_i \rightarrow V’_i$. We can thus assume (since $m < n$) that the image of $f_i$ has measure zero. Thus (by post-composing by a diffeomorphism), $f(U_i)$ has measure zero.
Hence $f(M)=\bigcup_i{f(U_i)}$ has measure zero.
Proof of the claim: Fix an open cover $\mathcal{U}_N$ such that the opens of $\mathcal{U}_N$ are diffeomorphic to open subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$.
Let $\mathcal{U}_M$ be an open cover of $M$ by open subspaces diffeomorphic to open subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^m$. Let $\mathcal{U}’_M$ be the open cover defined by the $U \cap f^{-1}(V)$ with $U \in \mathcal{U}_M$ and $V \in \mathcal{U}_N$.
Then $\mathcal{U}’_M$ is an open cover of $M$ by open subspaces diffeomorphic to open subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^m$ such that for any $U \in \mathcal{U}’_M$, $f(U)$ is contained in some element of $\mathcal{U}_N$.
Let $\mathcal{B}_M$ be a countable basis of the topology of $M$, and $\mathcal{B}’_M$ be collection of $U\in \mathcal{B}_M$ such that $U$ is conained in some element of $\mathcal{U}’_M$.
In particular, $\mathcal{B}’_M$ is a collection of open subspaces of $M$ satisfying the following conditions:

it is a countable basis of the topology of $M$,
any $U \in \mathcal{B}’_M$ is diffeomorphic to an open subspace of $\mathbb{R}^m$,
for any $U \in \mathcal{B}’_M$, $f(U)$ is contained in an open subspace of $V$ diffeomorphic to some open subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

In particular, choose, for each $U \in \mathcal{B}’_M$, an open subspace $V_U \supset f(U)$ of $V$ diffeomorphic to some open subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Then the faimilies $(U)_{U \in \mathcal{B}’_M}$ and $(V_U)_U$ fit the claim.

In Hirsch's book manifolds are not assumed to be second-countable. Is it necessary for the proof?

You need some sort of countability statement. After all, the disjoint union of uncountably many copies of $(0,1)$ covers (smoothly!) $(0,1)^2$.

OP: Note carefully the top of pp. 32-33 of Hirsch's book.
